# Multiply decision variable with the value of a dictionary

Tags: python, multiplication, gurobi

I write an optimization problem in Python that I will solve with Gurobi. However I do have a problem with one expression and I have no idea why it doesn´t work.

My decision variable `x[i,j]` is binary. I have a parameter `a[j]` which is a dictionary and contains keys of string names of `j` and the value of each `j` is a float number. 
My expression looks like this:

```
x[i,j]*a[j]
```

I want the model to take `j` of `x[i,j]` and multiply it with the corresponding `j` in `a[j]`. However the model will ALWAYS take the last element of `a[j]`. Why is that and what do I need to change so that the model takes the same `j` as in `x[i,j]`?? I also tried with for-loops but that won´t change anything.

To explain it a little bit in more detail:

My variables looks like this. I read a from an excel file:

```
m.addVars(i,j vtype=GRB.BINARY, name = "x")
a[j] = worksheet2.cell_value(x,2)
```

.... and the constraint is formulated like this:

```
m.addConstr((x[i,j]*a[j]) <= ((v*b[i])+(z[i]*c[i])), name="C7")
```

But the problem is the expression x[i,j] * a[j].. that does´nt work. As i said I also tried with for-loops for i and j, but without success.

j=["j1","j2",...]

a ={"j1":1.0; "j2":2.0;...}

Comment: Please update your question with some sample code and data to help us better visualise what your data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can come from importing the value of a[j] = worksheet2.cell_value(x,2). This cell_value(x,2) is fixed. After importation of a, you print i to verifie if the problem is there..

Comment: hmm actually i iterate over the x which is the row.. so the a[j] contains all possible j´s... it does look right.

Comment: Can you send a small version of the lp that is obtained with m.write ("File.lp") ?

Comment: yes so above is actually my whole constraint. Along with that goes the objective function: m.setObjective((quicksum(x[i,j] * e[i,j] for i in I for j in J))+ (quicksum(z[i] * c[i] for i in I)), GRB.MINIMIZE)

Comment: and my code for reading from excel looks like this: j=[]  
a = {}
for x in range(1,total_row_hallen):
  j = worksheet2.cell_value(x,0)
  halle.append(j)
  a[j] = worksheet2.cell_value(x,2)
  x+=1

Comment: is that what you were asking for?

Comment: Not exactly, but your code is logic. i say that, you can put in your code after the objective line or m.optimize() line,  m.write ("File.lp"). Gurobi will write your code in a file and then we can compare this file with what you tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the problem is due to the datatype of x which is a tupledict?

Answer (score 0):

No, I have done this exemple to test it, and it work. Indices of x are tuple 
    m=Model('Mine_LongTermes_5')

```
vX={}
for bl in Blocs:
   for e in OpEq:
     for t in Te:
         vX[bl,t,e]= m.addVar(vtype = GRB.BINARY,name = "vX_i{}_e{}_t{}".format(bl,e,t))
m.update()        
for bl in Blocs:
   for e in OpEq:
     for t in Te:
        m.addConstr((vX[bl,t,e]*OpEq_C[e]) <=  (58.0),name = "C04_1_IniX_i{}_t{}_e{}".format(bl,t,e))
m.update()
m.setObjective(quicksum([OpEq_P[e]*vX[bl,t,e] for bl in BlocsR for e in OpEq for t in Te]), GRB.MAXIMIZE)
m.update()
m.optimize()
```